# ¿Parte del complemento obligatorio o adjunto?

Tags: gramática

¿Son parte del complemento obligatorio del verbo o son adjuntos las construcciones resaltadas en las siguientes oraciones?

> Quisiera una taza de chocolate **con una barrita de Águila adentro**
>
> Quisiera una taza de café **servida amablemente**

Comment: La segunda es una cláusula reducida en participio equivalente a poner *... café que esté servida ...*

Answer (score 5):

Los complementos obligatorios son los directos, indirectos, de régimen y también atributo.

El resto, como por ejemplo el circunstancial son adjuntos, y creo que ambas frases pertenecen a esta categoría ya que describen, especifican y añaden más detalles, pero el verbo no los exige.

> El complemento circunstancial de Instrumento o Medio: añade información de con qué instrumento se realiza la acción verbal. Responde a la pregunta ¿Con qué?

En la segunda es el modo que quieres que te lo sirvan.

> El complemento circunstancial de modo, por su lado, explica de qué manera o modo se desempeña lo que el verbo expresa.

- ¿Cómo quieres que te sirva el café?
- Amablemente

Comment: El segundo no es complemento circunstancial. Es o *complemento predicativo* o *complemento de nombre*, si se considera que modifica a "taza". En mi opinión, complemento predicativo tiene más sentido porque la sustitución por un pronombre no incluiría al complemento: "La quisiera servida amablemente". Sea como sea, no es complemento circunstancial porque, por una parte, varía en género y número: "Quisiera unas tazas de café servidas amablemente"; y por otra, porque "amablemente" modifica a "servidas", no a "quiero", por lo que no podría ser el núcleo del sintagma "servidas amablemente".

Comment: El CC actúa como complemento del verbo 'servida'. Amablemente es un adverbio y estos siempre modifican los verbos.

Comment: "Servida" no es un verbo, es un participio actuando como un adjetivo. Si "amablemente" fuera el CC, entonces "amablemente" y "servida" pertenecerían a sintagmas distintos, lo cual no tiene sentido. Los adverbios no sólo modifican verbos. También pueden modificar a otros adverbios o a un adjetivo, como es en este caso.